# SImple C Program opening a file

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to make a program to open a file, called "write.txt".

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("write.txt", "w");
    return 0;
 }
```

Should this work? Because it returns nothing.

Comment: It returns nothing because you have a `return 0;` as the last statement? Or do you mean that `fopen()` is returning zero?

Comment: what do you expect it to return? What do you mean by return, print?

Comment: SOrry, I mean fopen returns nothing.

Comment: It cannot "return nothing".  What exactly does it return in your case?

Comment: SOrry. I mangled my words. I meant a file is not created or opened.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Other than an old variant of `main`, there's not really *much* wrong with that code. It should, barring errors, create the file.

However, since you're not checking the return value from `fopen`, you may get an error of some sort and not know about it.

I'd start with something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("write.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File not created, errno = %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("File created okay\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

If you're convinced that the file isn't being created but the above code says it is, then you may be a victim of the dreaded "IDE is working in a different directory from what you think" syndrome :-)

Some IDEs will actually run your code while they're in a directory like `<solution-name>\bin` or `<solution-name>\debug`. You can find out by putting:

```c
system("cd"); // for Windows
system("pwd") // for UNIXy systems
```

in to your code to see *where* it's running.

*That's* where a file will be created if you specify a relative path like `"write.txt"`. Otherwise, you can specify an absolute path to ensure it tries to create it at a specific point in the file system.

Comment: I believe functions declared without a return type are assumed to return an `int` in the older versions of the C language. This is **not** true for C++; the main function **is required** return an `int`.

Comment: I think you'll find from C99 onwards that you should return an int explicitly. C89/90 allowed defaults.

Comment: It's a good idea to close files that you open; it is OK to leave inherited files (like standard input and standard output) open on exit.

Comment: You'd be better to use `perror("File not created ok");` than the `printf()`, since it should print a user-readable error rather than an inscrutable error number.

Comment: Yes, I heartily agree, you _would_ be better off doing that. It also has nothing to do with the question per se :-) Think of it as just support code.

Answer (score 2):

What did you expect it to 'return' - it opens a file, on most platforms creating one if it doesn't exist.

You should probably fclose(fp) the file at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to print the contents of file write.txt. (Assume it contains characters).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{             

    FILE *fp,char ch;

    fp=fopen("write.txt","r");

    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Some problem in opening the file");
        exit(0);
    } 
    else
    { 
        while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
        {
            printf("%c",ch);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: The file is opened for writing, not reading. Also, your printf doesn't include errno so you won't know *why* the open failed. Use strerror or perror.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should study some more fundamentals in C before you start attempting to work with files. A return means some data is passed back to the calling code from the called function.In this case you return 0 at the end of your program. You did not do anything with your FILE pointer except cause a new file to be created...

Comment: I know. I mangled my question up. But what I meant was no file was opened/created. I'm trying to follow K&R p160-161.

Comment: K&R is a *horrible* tool for learning C, you'd be better off with something a little more modern.